pack() inside grid()-ed frames (and v.v.?
I may be the last programmer in the world to know this, but just in case ...
I've found dozens of forum threads that come close to this, but none that match exactly.  I struggled for a few hours with this error message: "_tkinter.TclError: cannot use geometry manager pack inside . which already has slaves managed by grid", which was rooted in code roughly like this:
frm = tk.Frame(root).grid(row=r,column=c)
lbl = tk.Label(frm).pack()

In my naivete, I thought that should work, because it looks like the layout of the frm frame should be independent of the layout of the container holding frm.  My solution?  First build the nested frame before adding it to the higher-level container:
frm = tk.Frame(root)
lbl = tk.Label(frm, text="Hello").pack()
frm.grid(row=r,column=c)

This works for me, and I'm a happy camper, but if an expert can show me a better solution, I can be even happier.

It appears that layout managers propagate downward in the container tree. I was surprised by that.

Could you improve your title please? A real question without abbreviation would be great. Take a [tour] if you have a few minutes.

pack or grid or place will all return None, so you end up having frm = None when None is given as the master-parameter then the default root will be used. So you basically do lbl = tk.Label(root). Therefore tkinter complains that you already used grid, since you gridded your frame and that's why you can't use pack here.

layout managers don't propagate down. They work only in the widget they were instructed to work in. Your problem is that frm was set to None, meaning that the label is a child of the root widget rather than the frame.

Does this answer your question? Why do I get "AttributeError: NoneType object has no attribute" using Tkinter? Where did the None value come from?

Thanks to all.  I'm not sure how to change the wording of the question; I'll have a go at that after a good night's sleep, after spending some quality time with "the tour".

If you use Python 3.8+, you can use the walrus operation :=: (frm := tk.Frame(root)).grid(...) and then (lbl := tk.Label(frm)).pack().
